# as: unrecognized option '-EL'

Tags: ubuntu, gcc

I have installed SimpleScalar and gcc compiler onto my Ubuntu machine using this [SCRIPT](https://github.com/sdenel/How-to-install-SimpleScalar-on-Ubuntu) (Installation went successfully)

When I try to compile simple c code I get this error

```
as: unrecognized option '-EL'
```

Google has not yield any results. Can anybody help with this issue?

Comment: `-EL` is not supported on all targets (including x86). What is your target? Can you verify the script has installed GNU `as`?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis as I am a beginner with Linux could you please elaborate?